# Simplify checking validation errors

Tags: laravel

it's not a problem, but I want to know if it's possible simplify this code line of laravel blade view:

```
@if ($errors->has('c1') || $errors->has('c2') || ... || $errors->has('cn'))
```

in something like this:

```
@if ($errors->has('c1', 'c2', ..., 'cn'))
```

I want to show the error in some parts of my form, depending of the variables that I check in this if statement.

Are there a short way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
@if ($errors->hasAny(['c1', 'c2', ...]))
   <p>To Do</p>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
@if ($errors->has('c1') || $errors->has('c2') || ... || $errors->has('cn'))
<span>{{$errors->first('c1')}}<span>
<span>{{$errors->first('c2')}}<span>
@endif
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But I want to simplify the if statement like: $errors->has('c1', 'c2', ..., 'cn');